# Can not access non-static field in a static context

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `UserControl` inside that a `StackPanel` in which i have dynamically added another `UserControl_1` more than 1 times. Now this child `UserControl_1` contains a `TextBox`.
I want to get the child `UserControl_1`'s `TextBox` value into Parent Container `UserControl`. How can i ?

In `UserControl_1` which contains the `TextBox` I've used this Property

```
    public static string ProductNameValue
    {
        get
        {
            return ProductNameBox.Text;
        }
    }
```

While in Parent UserControl i am using this to get value.

```
    string a = UserControl_1.ProductNameValue;
```

**Error shown can not access Non static field from static context**

**EDIT:**
Basically what i'm doing is Loading or adding a UserControl_1 many times That contains a TextBox Into Another Parent UserControl.
Now i want to get the TextBox value of Dynamically added UserControl_1 in Parent USerControl.

Comment: You need the instance of the `UserControl_1`-usercontrol. Then you can access the property.

Comment: sorry ! didn't  get what you are saying :(

Comment: but creating an instance of UserControl_1 will create a new instance in that case i wont be able to get the Input value of textbox by user ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Compiler : cannot access static method in a non-static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809550/c-sharp-compiler-cannot-access-static-method-in-a-non-static-context)

Comment: @SeM sir i don't see if it's a duplicate :(

Comment: UserControl_1 is an object, and you are trying to access a static property `ProductNameValue`, which will not happen since you need a class name

Comment: @MrinalKamboj then how can i access the value ?

Comment: @hammas_Stack Your question is about not being able to access non-static field in a static context and duplicate question answers why.

Comment: @SeM but that doesn't  solve the problem !

Answer (score 0):

A UserControl can have multiple instances. Which instance's textbox's value do you want to return from the static property? Hint: you don't know. Access the textbox through a reference to a `UserControl_1` instance instead

You say you're using this usercontrol in a "parent" (i.e. container) control. Then you must have a member referencing that control somewhere.

Assumung that member is simply called `this.userControl_1`, then you can make the string property of your user control nonstatic:

```
public string ProductNameValue
{
    get
    {
        return ProductNameBox.Text;
    }
}
```

And then in the containing control, you do:

```
var name = this.userControl_1.ProductNameValue;
```

Comment: sir ! kindly can you please review my edit what i am trying to do ? i am not understanding how to implement your solution ?

Comment: Your edit doesn't change anything. You need a reference to the control in order to get its instance's textbox's value. If you "dynamically generate" controls (don't use that term, in programming everything is dynamic, do you mean you create controls at runtime?), then you need to store a reference to them somewhere.

Comment: yes i am adding on run time ..on a button click ! and want to get the text box value that user will enter back into Parent control on a button click

Comment: So, again, save a reference to the control you create.